# Calculating the length of the given curve

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, curves, parametric

So I'm given the following curve.
$$(y-\arcsin(x))^2=1-x^2$$
I have to somehow get the parametric form of the equation and then calculate the length.
I class whenever we have to do this kinds of things we always let $y=tx$ and then everything was fine and easy, but here that doesn't seem to work. If you could maybe help me with this beautiful problem, I'd be forever grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: R. You can easily do $$y=\sin^{-1}(x)\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}\implies (x,\sin^{-1}(x)\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}),$$ or try polar coordinates.

Comment: Let’s switch the polar coordinates so that $y=\cos(t),x=\sin(t)\implies (\cos(t)-t)^2=\cos^2(t)$